# How to trigger voice lines?

Tags: overwatch

I just unlocked and equipped a new Voice Line.

How to I trigger them? 
Is there a button for it?
Do heroes say their Voice Lines automatically after certain number of kills?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in game you can push "C" (default key binding) and it will bring up an overlay with different options. Simply click on the one that says voice line.

[image]

Comment: @JoãoNeves it took me a bit to find it at first. I just started pushing random keys, and was like oh, that's where it was hiding.

Comment: You can also bind a key to every action/line available in the wheel from the control settings.

Answer (score 2):

The "voice line" is an option available through the quick chat menu.

You can access the quick chat menu by pressing the <kbd>C</kbd> button, on computer, or by holding down on the d-pad, on console.